# Content Provider Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Created a profile using  content provider. After running it correctly, added 3 fields to the table. But now its not working correctly.It shows an error like `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d2`.Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, try to do Project|Force Clean. If you are working outside of Eclipse, run `ant clean`. Your error message is probably because your resources, the generated `R.java` file, and some of your other compiled code are collectively out of sync.